# Java: use instance class's static variable in base class method

Tags: java

I have an abstract class that has a static final variable and an instance method defined that references that variable, and I have a non-abstract class that extends that class and overrides the variable:

**AClass.java**

```
public abstract class AClass {
    static final int number = 1;

    public void meth(){
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

**IClass.java**

```
public class IClass extends AClass{
    static final int number = 2;
}
```

I want `meth()` to print the actual object's class's `number`, but when I call it with an `IClass` object, I always get `1`, regardless of how it's defined:

```
AClass o1 = new IClass();
o1.meth(); // 1
IClass o2 = new IClass();
o2.meth(); // 1
new IClass().meth(); // 1
```

I've added an override that calls the super to `IClass`, but that didn't help:

**IClass.java**

```
public class IClass extends AClass{
    static final int number = 2;

    @Override
    public void meth(){
        super.meth();
    }
}
```

I've also tried usin `this` in `meth()`:

**AClass.java**

```
public abstract class AClass {
    static final int number = 1;

    public void meth(){
        System.out.println(this.number);
    }
}
```

Can this be done without completely rewriting the method in **IClass.java**?

Comment: The point is that you can't **override** static fields. You resolve the problem by not doing such things. You avoid static where possible; and if you want to adhere to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle then you do that using non-static methods! And you know; given your reputation: what kind of prior research did you do?

Comment: You can't override instance fields, either.